# How can I use my GPass data?

Tags: software-recommendation, 11.10, password

There are two parts here:

1. It appears that [GPass is dropped in oneiric](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+source/gpass/+bug/770994) so can anyone recommend a new password manager?
2. Is there a way to open the file created with GPass, or do I need to recover the passwords in another install of GPass and manually move the passwords into the recommended replacement?

Comment: I recommend KeePassX.

Comment: I have just tired KeePassX but it doesn't import gpass database. I am sure it works well for other needs though. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been trying out a few password managers.

[Revelation](http://freshmeat.net/projects/revelation/) can import gpass databases and even looks and works the same as gpass.

It is in the repositories in oneiric.

It imports gpass (otherwise known as Gnome Password Manager), passwords just fine (the user below's problems notwithstanding).  I just did it.

To import from gpass click File->Import.  Browse to your .gpass directory, pick your passwords.gps file, and pick 'Gpass 0.5x or newer' as the filetype. (It does not seem to automatically detect the filetype).  Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this PPA for gpass:

https://launchpad.net/~stanray/+archive/gpass052

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any luck getting Revelation to import my gpass password file, so i just installed the natty version of gpass from here.

http://linuxappfinder.com/package/gpass

Download the .deb file, double click on it.  After install all runs as before.

Comment: Did you try to manually specify file type in import window as said in previous comment?

Answer (score 0):

1. - Keepassx is fine, but it depends on your needs. I recommend it because it allows you to choose where to save DB, so you can sync it (with U1 i.e.) without tricks.
2. - It is not easy to export them because they are - off course - encrypted. But there is a project here https://github.com/ueno/gpass-export for this purpose. The software should extract them and then it is up to you :)

Hope it helps,

Comment: UPDATE: I've seen that also Revelation allows you to select where save the database